# Performance degradation with RHEL 6.5 and Apache Camel 2.15.0

Tags: java, apache-camel, redhat

I am using Apache Camel 2.15.0 version in my web application and using the Rest Component for defining the REST endpoints using Java DSL.

The application runs properly with Windows platform and Ubuntu 16.04, however I had seen the very poor performance while testing with the RHEL 6.5 and 7.3.

After enabling the logs for RHEL, I had noticed that for each HTTP request it takes long time from Servlet Filter to the RouteBuilder.

What can be the possible causes behind this ?

I am attaching the logs to get better idea:

```
2017-01-10 12:28:37,005 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:28:37,005 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:28:37,005 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:28:38,728 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:28:38,729 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:28:38,729 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement []
2017-01-10 12:28:38,729 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,730 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,731 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:28:38,731 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:28:38,731 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement []
2017-01-10 12:28:38,731 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,734 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,790 [DEBUG] - >>>> Endpoint[bean://m?method=getDynamicMessagesForSection%28%24%7Bheader.owner%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.owner_roles%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.section%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.timezone%7D%29] Exchange[HttpMessage@0x6f043df0]
2017-01-10 12:28:38,790 [DEBUG] - >>>> Endpoint[bean://m?method=getDynamicMessagesForSection%28%24%7Bheader.owner%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.owner_roles%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.section%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.timezone%7D%29] Exchange[HttpMessage@0x6f043df0]
2017-01-10 12:28:38,790 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'm'
2017-01-10 12:28:38,790 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:28:38,791 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:28:38,791 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement
2017-01-10 12:28:38,791 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,793 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,793 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: []
2017-01-10 12:28:38,793 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: []
2017-01-10 12:28:38,793 [DEBUG] - Processing onAfterRoute: Exchange[Message: [ ]]
2017-01-10 12:28:38,793 [DEBUG] - Processing onAfterRoute: Exchange[Message: [ ]]
2017-01-10 12:28:38,794 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:28:38,794 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:28:38,794 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement 
2017-01-10 12:28:38,794 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,796 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,796 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: 2
2017-01-10 12:28:38,796 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: 2
2017-01-10 12:28:38,797 [DEBUG] - Streaming response in chunked mode with buffer size 8192
2017-01-10 12:28:38,797 [DEBUG] - Streaming response in chunked mode with buffer size 8192
2017-01-10 12:28:38,985 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:28:38,986 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:28:38,986 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement 
2017-01-10 12:28:38,986 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,986 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:28:38,986 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:28:38,986 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement 
2017-01-10 12:28:38,986 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,988 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,988 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:28:38,988 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:28:38,988 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement 
2017-01-10 12:28:38,989 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,989 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,989 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:28:38,990 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:28:38,990 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement 
2017-01-10 12:28:38,990 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,991 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:38,997 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:39,954 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:28:39,954 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:28:39,954 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement
2017-01-10 12:28:39,954 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:39,956 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:39,956 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:28:39,957 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:28:39,957 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement
2017-01-10 12:28:39,957 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:39,958 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:28:56,193 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:28:56,193 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:28:57,007 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:28:57,007 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:29:17,013 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:29:17,013 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:29:26,167 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:29:26,167 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:29:37,015 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:29:37,015 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:29:55,218 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:29:55,218 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:29:56,051 [DEBUG] - >>>> Endpoint[bean://q?method=getAllRoles%28%24%7Bheader.owner%7D%29] Exchange[HttpMessage@0x77233160]
2017-01-10 12:29:56,051 [DEBUG] - >>>> Endpoint[bean://q?method=getAllRoles%28%24%7Bheader.owner%7D%29] Exchange[HttpMessage@0x77233160]
2017-01-10 12:29:56,051 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'q'
2017-01-10 12:29:56,051 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:29:56,051 [DEBUG] - Executing SQL query []
2017-01-10 12:29:56,051 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:29:56,052 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:29:56,052 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: []
2017-01-10 12:29:56,052 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: []
2017-01-10 12:29:56,053 [DEBUG] - Processing onAfterRoute: Exchange[Message: [ ]]
2017-01-10 12:29:56,053 [DEBUG] - Processing onAfterRoute: Exchange[Message: [ ]]
2017-01-10 12:29:56,053 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:29:56,053 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:29:56,053 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement []
2017-01-10 12:29:56,053 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:29:56,054 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:29:56,054 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: 2
2017-01-10 12:29:56,054 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: 2
2017-01-10 12:29:56,055 [DEBUG] - Streaming response in chunked mode with buffer size 8192
2017-01-10 12:29:56,055 [DEBUG] - Streaming response in chunked mode with buffer size 8192
2017-01-10 12:29:57,020 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:29:57,020 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:30:16,234 [DEBUG] - >>>> Endpoint[bean://f?method=getFilesAndFolder%28%24%7Bheader.category%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.owner%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.archiveMode%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.timezone%7D%29] Exchange[HttpMessage@0x79501044]
2017-01-10 12:30:16,234 [DEBUG] - >>>> Endpoint[bean://f?method=getFilesAndFolder%28%24%7Bheader.category%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.owner%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.archiveMode%7D%2C%24%7Bheader.timezone%7D%29] Exchange[HttpMessage@0x79501044]
2017-01-10 12:30:16,234 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'f'
2017-01-10 12:30:16,234 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:30:16,234 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:30:16,234 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement []
2017-01-10 12:30:16,234 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:30:16,235 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:30:16,235 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:30:16,235 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:30:16,236 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement 
2017-01-10 12:30:16,236 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:30:16,239 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:30:16,239 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: [Offices1/xmlDATASETSAdminPVT1Admin2017-01-09 16:30:50.012017-01-09 16:30:50.0Admin]
2017-01-10 12:30:16,239 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: [Offices1/xmlDATASETSAdminPVT1Admin2017-01-09 16:30:50.012017-01-09 16:30:50.0Admin]
2017-01-10 12:30:16,240 [DEBUG] - Processing onAfterRoute: Exchange[Message: [ ]]
2017-01-10 12:30:16,240 [DEBUG] - Processing onAfterRoute: Exchange[Message: []]
2017-01-10 12:30:16,240 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:30:16,240 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:30:16,240 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement []
2017-01-10 12:30:16,240 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:30:16,241 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:30:16,241 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: 2
2017-01-10 12:30:16,241 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: 2
2017-01-10 12:30:16,242 [DEBUG] - Streaming response in chunked mode with buffer size 8192
2017-01-10 12:30:16,242 [DEBUG] - Streaming response in chunked mode with buffer size 8192
2017-01-10 12:30:17,020 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:30:17,020 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:30:22,175 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:30:22,175 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:30:31,056 [DEBUG] - >>>> Endpoint[bean://u?method=getAllUsers%28%24%7Bheader.userName%7D%29] Exchange[HttpMessage@0x272487ca]
2017-01-10 12:30:31,056 [DEBUG] - >>>> Endpoint[bean://u?method=getAllUsers%28%24%7Bheader.userName%7D%29] Exchange[HttpMessage@0x272487ca]
2017-01-10 12:30:31,056 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'u'
2017-01-10 12:30:31,056 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:30:31,057 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:30:31,057 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement [select * from ai_user]
2017-01-10 12:30:31,057 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:30:31,059 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:30:31,059 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: [com.b.UserBean@7d6cbe02]
2017-01-10 12:30:31,059 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: [com.b.UserBean@7d6cbe02]
2017-01-10 12:30:31,061 [DEBUG] - Processing onAfterRoute: Exchange[Message: []]
2017-01-10 12:30:31,061 [DEBUG] - Processing onAfterRoute: Exchange[Message: []]
2017-01-10 12:30:31,063 [DEBUG] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2017-01-10 12:30:31,063 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL query
2017-01-10 12:30:31,063 [DEBUG] - Executing prepared SQL statement
2017-01-10 12:30:31,063 [DEBUG] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-01-10 12:30:31,064 [DEBUG] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-01-10 12:30:31,064 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: 2
2017-01-10 12:30:31,064 [DEBUG] - Setting bean invocation result on the OUT message: 2
2017-01-10 12:30:31,065 [DEBUG] - Streaming response in chunked mode with buffer size 8192
2017-01-10 12:30:31,065 [DEBUG] - Streaming response in chunked mode with buffer size 8192
2017-01-10 12:30:37,042 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:30:37,042 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:30:50,462 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:30:50,462 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:30:57,034 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:30:57,034 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:31:17,031 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:31:17,031 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:31:18,901 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:31:18,901 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:31:37,035 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:31:37,035 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:31:43,373 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:31:43,373 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:31:57,033 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:31:57,033 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:32:07,289 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:32:07,289 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:32:17,033 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:32:17,033 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:32:34,610 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:32:34,610 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:32:37,037 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:32:37,037 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:32:57,038 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:32:57,038 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:32:59,451 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:32:59,451 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:33:17,039 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:33:17,039 [DEBUG] - ClusterManager: Check-in complete.
2017-01-10 12:33:22,677 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2017-01-10 12:33:22,677 [DEBUG] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
```

Comment: Check this ideas on the subject: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/01/performance-tuning-ideas-apache-camel.html